# Bloated JS from Coffeescript which wants to return everything

Tags: coffeescript

I've got this Coffeescript here:

```
brew = (args...) =>
  for e in args
    alert e
    null

brew('fo', 're', 'eo');
```

I wish I didn't need to put null there to get it to work, but alas, that compiles to this:

```
brew = function() {
  var args, e, _i, _len, _results;
  args = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = args.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    e = args[_i];
    alert(e);
    _results.push(null);
  }
  return _results;
};

brew('fo', 're', 'eo');
```

But now I have 3 unnecessary lines:

```
 _results = [];
 _results.push(null);
 return _results;
```

Any tips?

Comment: i think the problem here is that you don't make it explicit that you don't want to return anything—which you should! personally i'm not very fond of CoffeeScript's 'implicit return' policy, but i don't like my functions to return arbitrary / unintended / confusing values either, so i make it my policy to always exit such functions with `return null`. don't be afraid of an extra line when it helps to make your code clearer! and, by the way, your `null` should definitely be outdented one step, it definitely does not belong inside the loop.

Comment: @flow: There is a difference between `return` and `return null`. I'm not terribly fond of the implicit return stuff either, except for one-liners of course (`f = (x) -> x * x` and similar things). I do agree that all the optional stuff tends to make things harder to understand though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
brew = (args...) -> args.forEach alert
```

which compiles to

```
var brew,
    __slice = [].slice;

brew = function() {
  var args;
  args = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
  return args.forEach(alert);
};

brew('fo', 're', 'eo');
```

Comment: that's certainly possible, but is it idiomatic CoffeeScript? i'd much prefer to write `alert x for x in args` and end my function with `return null` (see my comment above).

Comment: It's not idiomatic CoffeScript but it's what people understand better, in my experience at work colleagues are puzzled by your example and this `run() if hasShoesOn()`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a function to return anything, say so:

```
brew = (args...) =>
  for e in args
    console.log e
  return
```

A side effect of that is that the `for` loop won't populate an array: CoffeeScript can guarantee that the result of the `for` loop expression won't be used so it won't bother calculating it. Keep in mind that everything is an expression in CoffeeScript and functions return the value of their last expression so sometimes you have to throw in explicit `return`s to avoid wasting time computing things that will never get used.

That CoffeeScript loop ends up like this:

```
for (_i = 0, _len = args.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  e = args[_i];
  console.log(e);
}
```

Note that the explicit "return nothing" `return` suppresses all the `_result` stuff.

You can see it yourself [over here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3abrew%20=%20%28args...%29%20=%3E%0A%20%20for%20e%20in%20args%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20e%0A%20%20return%0A%0Abrew%281,%202,%203,%204%29%0A).